# How can I access my local website with domain name under xampp using apache dns server instead of ip address in a LAN network?

Tags: php, apache, dns

I'm a computer engineering student and I've developed a web project for my thesis. I've already developed my project using Xampp in a LAN network. I use Apache in Xampp for Domain name in LAN to access from any other computers. But, however, I've configured any Apache configuration files, my website(example-www.techlibrary.com)can't be call with it's domain name instead of it's ip address(example-192.168.43.10). How can I do this???

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access your Xampp in Local Area with DNS Name, you have to edit your **hosts** file.

Under Windows you find it in c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Then put this line in it

```
192.168.43.10 example-www.techlibrary.com
```

and you can reach on this pc example-www.techlibary.com

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this :

1. Set up a local DNS server which will resolve the name for the machines on the network. I recommend using linux. Note that you would have to configure the machines to use this machine as the DNS :

   http://www.aboutdebian.com/dns.htm
2. An easier way to achieve this is to edit the hosts file of your machines if the number of machines is less. Note that you would need admin access for that.


   Windows : `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`
   Linux : `/etc/hosts`
   Edit the file according to the link below.

   http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...@Shikhar Bhardwaj. But I've never used linux. I'm now using Windows7 and please recommend me which local DNS server is good for windows. On the other hand, editing the host files in LAN network is not a possible way for me because in my testing LAN, there are various machines. please reply me....